# are pointers released from memory when c++ program end?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

This is a beginner question but I learned programming with c# and I am now moving to c++ and now that I am working with pointers, I know that I have to free them from memory when I'm done with them but when the program is closed are they removed from the memory or do they stay there?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When your program ends, all the memory it used (whether dynamically allocated or not) is returned to the operating system.  It doesn't matter if it's a C program, a C++ program, a C# program, or any other kind of program you might be writing.

Now, just because the OS will reclaim the memory doesn't mean you can be cavalier about memory management.  While your program runs, you should try to take care of freeing any memory you're done with.  Not doing so will cause "memory leaks", and those can certainly affect your program and the system it's running on, at least while your program is running.

Comment: @MatthieuM. How about Palm OS? :D

Comment: Any operating system based on the concept of orthogonal persistence would introduce wrinkles into a problem like this, I suppose.

Comment: But not calling `delete` on a class object whos destructor does produce side effects will lead to not only memory leak but Undefined Behavior, so not doing so is not advisable at all.

Comment: @Als, that's true.  I think the OP's question is "Am I going to fill up all the memory on my computer if I have memory leak bugs in my code?", and the answer to that is "No, when your program exits, the memory it used is recovered by the OS."

Comment: @MatthieuM. Novell NetWare is one such. You have to release everything, and I do mean everything: memory, files, sockets, semaphores, ... or else it crashes. 'It' being NetWare. Windows 3 wasn't much better in this respect.

Answer (score 2):

Note that its not the pointer that needs deallocation but the pointed object.

The answer depends on type of memory the pointers point to:

- If the pointer points to automatic object then the objects are cleaned implicitly.
- If the pointer points to objects allocated dynamically using `new` or `new []` or `malloc` or `calloc`, then they need to be explicitly deallocated by resp calling `delete` or `delete []` or `free`.

Note that it is advisable to Use dynamic allocations sparingly and if you must, Use Smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

**EDIT:**
If your question is:
**What happens if your program doesn't deallocate memory and exits?**

Answer is:
OS reclaims it. The OS simply takes back all the memory it allocated to a process it does not understand whether your program leaked memory or not.
But it is always a good practice to clean up your own mess yourself.
If you have an class who's destructor does have code with side-effects then not calling `delete` on the dynamically allocated pointer results in Undefined Behavior and it renders your code completely dangling at compilers mercy.

Comment: Unless he allocated memory for a pointer. But he seems to be asking three or four questions at once. The question is ambiguous.

Comment: I don't think the question is ambiguous.  It says "when the program is closed are they removed from the memory or do they stay there", and the answer is that OS the reclaims all memory used the process when that process terminates.

Comment: You can short-circuit most of what he wrote and leave him with that answer but between the first half of his sentence and the second half of it there are other considerations that haven't been addressed. Which leads me to believe that he has other questions that he didn't ask directly. He's specifically asking about pointers themselves, which to me makes the question awkward.

Answer (score -2):

The memory allocated by you ( e.g. using the New keyword) will remain there unless you delete it! If you are talking about the pointer itself, then yes! At the end of your program the pointer will just get wiped out!

Comment: Thank you! This means that bad written code can lead to slowing down the computer even after the program is closed. Is there a freeall(); method or semothing like that that can be placed at the end of the program?

Comment: @Mostaguen, no.  This answer is wrong.  You don't need to have a `freeall` or anthing like that.  When the program ends, its memory is all reclaimed by the OS.

Comment: @Mostaguen, In some cases it might be better to forget about freeing a lot of such memory right at the end because it will leave your application hanging there after the user closes it. Freeing memory allocated repeatedly is important to avoid memory leaks, but if it's only allocated once and happens to be quite large, I'd prefer the application closing and the OS taking care of it rather than sitting there waiting while the application "does nothing for 10 seconds".

Comment: This answer is invalid on modern user-oriented operating systems when dealing with the specific "after the program is closed" state. On certain embedded operating systems it may still be valid but those are a very big exception, not the norm.

Comment: @mah, do you know any embedded operating systems that behave in such a way?  I think to be called an "operating system" and not an "executive" or something like that would require this kind of memory management feature.

Comment: @Carl Norum I don't know specifically of any anymore, it's quite a long time since I've been immersed in that world and examined many systems. I agree with you that one may be more likely to call them something other than operating system but the term operating system has wide usage such that I don't believe it would be unheard of.