# How a dynamically allocated object is deleted if an error occur in the program in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was wondering how a dynamically allocated object is deleted if an error occured in the program. Imagine this one:

```
int main() {
  int *ptr = new int();

  int result = 15 / 0;

  delete ptr;
}
```

Division by 0 is completely impossible, so the int associated to the ptr will never be deleted?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875177/are-pointers-released-from-memory-when-c-program-end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [are pointers released from memory when c++ program end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875177/are-pointers-released-from-memory-when-c-program-end)

Comment: Note that, in this case, division by zero is a valid operation and does not result in program exiting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745311/c-division-by-0. And so `delete ptr;` will indeed get called.

Comment: @HKrishnan integer division by zero causes undefined behaviour, the question you link to is about floating point division

Comment: (BTW floating division by 0 also causes undefined behaviour, which the compiler might or might not manifest by performing IEEE behaviour)

Comment: @M.M Right, sorry, didn't realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How a dynamically allocated object is deleted if an error occur in the program in C++?

It **isn't** deleted.

And because the pointer value will be lost, it cannot ever be deleted. This is known as a memory leak.

> Division by 0 is completely impossible, so the int associated to the ptr will never be deleted?

Note that behaviour of division by zero is undefind. Therefore there is no guarantee that there would be an error.

---

If a program terminates abnormally, then there will be some memory that was not freed. This leak is fine because the program is being terminated. The operating system will recover all memory that was reserved for the process.

More problematic case is exceptions, which may be caught, and program may continue executing. For a program to be exception safe, you must not perform operations that may potentially throw while holding an owning bare pointer. In fact, you should avoid owning bare pointers as much as possible. Instead, use RAII containers and smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

you should use "smart pointer" that allows deallocation even if an exception is throws before your call.

```
unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int());
```

The smart pointer contains the raw pointer and is allowed to delete him.

Here is the doc :
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=vs-2019

Comment: It's true that you should use smart pointers, however this program has undefined behaviour then anything can happen (including not executing destructors)